# Find $H<G$ so that $\{(x, y) | xx^{−1} y^{−1} \in H\}$ is not an equivalence relation on $G$.

Tags: group-theory, examples-counterexamples, abelian-groups, equivalence-relations

The question is as follows:

Find an example of a group $G$ with a subgroup $H$ so that
$$\{(x, y) | xx^{−1} y^{−1} \in H\}$$
is not an equivalence relation on $G$.

I've just been working on this problem set for hours now and I'm having a hard time coming up with an example for this question.

Comment: Take $x \in G$ such that $x \notin H$ Then you are done. So take $G= \Bbb Z$ and $H=2\Bbb Z.$ Then $1 \not\sim 1.$ So reflexive property of the relation $\sim$ is violated.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $G=V=\Bbb Z_2\times \Bbb Z_2$ given by the presentation $$\langle a, b\mid a^2, b^2, ab=ba\rangle$$ and the subgroup $H\cong \Bbb Z_2$ given by $\langle b\mid b^2\rangle$. Pick $a\in G\setminus H$. Then $a\not\sim a$.

---

Another way to see this is that the condition $xx^{-1}y^{-1}\in H$ is equivalent to $ey^{-1}=y^{-1}\in H$, which is in turn equivalent to $y\in H$ since $H$ is a subgroup of $G$. Thus it is sufficient to let $x\in G\setminus H$ in order for $x\not\sim x$; that is, for reflexivity to fail.

Comment: when you use the notation following "given by..." are those the generators of the subgroup ?

Comment: Almost. They are [group presentations](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_of_a_group), @GwenDi.

Comment: I've added to the answer, @GwenDi.